# c# image send improvement

Tags: image, sockets, screen, share

im trying to send as much pictures as possible per sec and it's working prettry good on local network,but when im trying it from friend computer or somthning... it works veryyyy slowwww.. i have a prettry good internet,also my friend has..  i have only this port opend.....

i think it might be realted to image compression or somthing...

this is the client's code

```
 private void startSend()
 {
    sck = client.Client;
    s = new NetworkStream(sck);

    while (true)
    {
        Bitmap screeny = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics theShot = Graphics.FromImage(screeny);
        theShot.ScaleTransform(.25F, .25F);
        theShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        BinaryFormatter bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();

       bFormat.Serialize(s, screeny);

       theShot.Dispose();
       screeny.Dispose();

       Thread.Sleep(20);
   }
}
```

server is:

```
    public void startListening()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10);
        listener.Start();

         stream= listener.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();

         while (true)
         {
             BinaryFormatter bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
             Bitmap inImage = bFormat.Deserialize(stream) as Bitmap;

             theImage.Image = (Image)inImage;
         }
    }
```

these both methods work on thread... it's really slow even i tried to set sleep to 3000ms....

any idea guys how can i send it faster? idk nothing about compression so if someone could help guys.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Zip the File before sending:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Try adding these methods to Client:

```
byte[] Compress(byte[] b)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
            using (GZipStream z = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            z.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Changing your call to:

```
byte[] compressed = Compress(ImageToByte(screeny));
bFormat.Serialize(s, compressed);
```

And Add these to server:

```
byte[] Decompress(byte[] b)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bs = new MemoryStream(b))
        using (var z = new GZipStream(bs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            z.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        return new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}
```

And change inside the while block on server to:

```
BinaryFormatter bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();

byte[] inBytes = bFormat.Deserialize(stream) as byte[];
Bitmap inImage = ByteToImage(Decompress(inBytes ));

theImage.Image = (Image)inImage;
```

Comment: i dont really understand bro.. how can  i send a zip to the server after?.. and lets say i managed to to this how can i unzip it in the other side? isnt is sound too long and complex i mean  in terms of Efficiency..

Comment: If you run local and your code is fast and on the network it takes time, your problem is with network traffic. You compress on client and decompress on server, its not that complex...

Comment: Im working on something now, later i can post how to do it in your code

Comment: allright ty very much bro! i would really like to see ur code :D